# GWO Test: Multiple test pages not working within preview

Tags: javascript, testing, google-website-optimizer

So it's my first time doing a multi-page multivariate test but was told everything would work just fine with my code. Google verified my code and it was ready to go live but when previewing the test it only showed variation 1 on the page I said the test was running on, it never appeared on the other pages the code was on. Also, instead of a conversion page I am using an onclick function on a link to trigger the goal. I used the code from GWO to do this and when testing locally it seemed to fire off just fine. All pages with the test include the same test file.

The test is setup like this: 
- Original: Several category pages of products within an ecommerce site.
- Variation 1: Those categories now display a banner ad in the left-hand navigation. If someone clicks the banner, it sends off as a conversion, then it takes them off-site.

The preview only shows the first category working as expected, but on the other categories it doesn't show at all. I would love to define which pages the test is on as well as which pages GWO could expect the conversion to be on, but GWO only wants 1 page.

So what am I doing wrong? What am I missing to make this multiple-page test work?  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at other tests done by colleagues that use multiple pages, the preview behavior worked in the same manner. So I turned the test on and monitored it - it worked as planned. I think the preview in GWO as it is now just gets confused when doing multiple pages since it only allows for one test and one conversion page. I hope with the new Experiments this will improve.